# How do I fix CURL error "Could not resolve host"?

Tags: windows, curl

I am trying to make a POST request on windows console with some json data and I get this error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: John,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: lName
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Doe,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: phone
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 0123456789,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: passwd
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: myPassword,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: tosAgm
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 5
{}
```

The request looks like this:

```
curl -d '{"fName": "John", "lName": "Doe", "phone": "0123456789", "passwd": "myPassword", "tosAgm": "true"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/users
```

After doing some research I found that the request is correct, so why am I getting this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape double-quotes

```
curl -d '{\"fName\": \"John\", ...
```

Comment: Are you running curl on a Windows OS? Then change your single-quotes by double-quotes while preserving JSON quote escaping. Just tried on a Windows system the following command that was successful: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"fName\": \"John\", \"lName\": \"Doe\", \"phone\": \"0123456789\", \"passwd\": \"myPassword\", \"tosAgm\": \"true\"}" http://localhost:3000/tst`

Comment: It's windows, yeah. It worked. Then I removed the escaping and it also worked, so it looks like the missing outer quotes was creating the error. Thanks.